# How to configure persistent login for Blazor WebAssembly and IdentityServer 4?

Tags: blazor, identityserver4, progressive-web-apps, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

We have a standalone Blazor WebAssembly App (PWA) where users need to authenticate (OIDC) themselves via IdentityServer 4 (with default settings). IdentityServer then returns an access token which the app uses to call several api's. Most users use the app on a mobile device and need to use the application once they receive a notification (once or twice each hour). Everything is working quite well, but since a users login does not persist during the day, they need to reauthenticate themselves multiple times a day. For users this is really annoying behavior. Therefore, I am looking  for a solution where the users login is persisted for at least x hours. I read several blogs and tried to change the settings on IdentityServer, but I just can't seem to change this behavior.

**Actual behavior:**

- When a user's session is closed, the user is logged out and needs to login again on IdentityServer.
- After approximately 1 hour the user is logged out either way.

**Expected behavior:**

- A user's login is persisted across multiple sessions, e.g. for a total time of x hours (I don't actually know if this is possible?).
- As long as a user is logged in and the application is active (in the background) the user stays authenticated.

It would already help a lot if a user keeps authenticated as long as it uses the app. However, the only settings with a value of 1 hour (that I can find in IdentityServer) is the access token lifetime, which defaults to 3600 seconds. I also read, though, that this has nothing to do with my problem that a user has to reauthenticate itself.

I think I'm overlooking something, but I just can't figure out how to fix this. Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

In my Blazor WebAssembly project I have the following configuration in `Program.cs`

```cs
      builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("IdentityService", options.ProviderOptions);
            });

And in appsettings.json:

    "IdentityService": {
        "Authority": "https://localhost:44362",
        "ClientId": "MyBlazorClient",
        "DefaultScopes": [
            "openid",
            "profile",
            "claims",
            "roles"
        ],
        "ResponseType": "code"
    },
```

In IdentityServer I got the following in my `StartUp.cs`

```cs
    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Account/Login";
                options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Account/Logout";
                options.Authentication = new AuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(8), 
                    CookieSlidingExpiration = true
                };
            })
```

And last, this is my client configuration in IdentityServer:

```cs
    new Client
    {
        ClientId = "MyBlazorClient",
        ClientName = "My Blazor Client Application",
        RequireClientSecret = false,
        AllowedCorsOrigins = { https://localhost:443 },
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
        RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:443/authentication/login-callback" },
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:443/authentication/logout-callback" },
        AllowedScopes = new List<string>
        {
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
            "roles",
            "claims"
        },
        RequirePkce = true,
        AllowPlainTextPkce = false,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the question with your `Startup.cs` file and all the Identity/Authentication configuration?

Chances are you are not setting the Application Cookie which Identity Server will honor. Here's an example:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyAppCookie";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/error";
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
});
```

Comment: I updated the question with my identity configuration.

Comment: You should still try adding the Application Cookie as Identity Server uses those settings to configure it.